# Jest react keycloak client instance is not defined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

In my react application I have a function which is using keycloak instance like in code below

```js
function fetchUrlWithAuthentication(url) {
  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.set('Authorization', `Bearer ${keycloakClient.token}`);
  return fetch(url, {
    headers,
  });
}
```

in Jest file i'm getting error:  `keycloakClient is not defined`

I tried to define in `beforeEach` keycloak instance but it didnt help, any suggestions how to fix this error ?

```js
  beforeEach(() => {
    const keycloakClient = Keycloak({
      url: 'https://www.test.de/auth',
      realm: 'realm',
      clientId: 'clientId',
    });
    originalOpen = window.open;
    window.open = jest.fn().mockName('window.open');
  });
```

Comment: Given your `keycloakClient` in the test code is locally defined in the `beforeEach` callback and never actually _used_ anywhere, it's hard to say why you think that would help. It's also not clear where the _real_ value's supposed to come from. Give a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

because your `keycloakClient`  is not accessible from outside of your beforeEach scope.
You have to declare your keycloackClient variable outside with a `let` and then in beforeEach, `keycloaclCLient = Keycloack(...)`

Comment: I just tried it bit still the same error "keycloakClient is not defined"

Comment: ok, where are you using that function `fetchUrlWithAuthentication` ? can you Give a minimal reproducible example of your test suite ?